# How to increase array items on each click?

Tags: php, session, multidimensional-array, php-5.3

I want to store images in an array on every click before sending the data for database injection.

Below is my dummy test, but I can't get my head around to increase/ store the images array,

```
<?php
function add_image($image = array())
{
    # Loop and rename the table.
    foreach($image as $key => $item) 
    {
        $images[] = array(
            'image_id' => $image[$key]['image_id'],
            'image_title' => $image[$key]['image_title']
        );
    }

    return $images;
}

if($_REQUEST['add'] == '1')
{
    $image = array(
        array(
            'image_id' => 1,
            'image_title' => 'test 1'
        )
    );

    $images = add_image($image);

    var_dump($images);
}
if($_REQUEST['add'] == '2')
{
    $image = array(
        array(
            'image_id' => 2,
            'image_title' => 'test 2'
        )
    );

    $images = add_image($image);

    var_dump($images);
}           
?>
<a href="array_session.php?add=1">add 1</a>
<a href="array_session.php?add=2">add 2</a>
```

I will get a fresh image array on each click like this,

```
 array
      0 => 
        array
          'image_id' => int 1
          'image_title' => string 'test 1' (length=6)
```

or,

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'image_id' => int 2
      'image_title' => string 'test 2' (length=6)
```

instead of

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'image_id' => int 1
      'image_title' => string 'test 1' (length=6)
1 => 
    array
      'image_id' => int 2
      'image_title' => string 'test 2' (length=6)
```

Is it to do with session that I should be using?

Comment: thanks. how do I use session to store these data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP session is really easy to use, you should start by reading documentation.

Here is an example :

```
// start session
session_start();

// init session var
if (!isset($_SESSION['images'])) $_SESSION['images'] = array();
```

After that, you just have to use $_SESSION['images'] to store your images data.